# how to save the audio player current play time i.e 1:45/25:40 in audio player using android studio?

Tags: android, audio

i want to my android app to save the instance of playtime of audio where we have paused or closed the app. so that we can play the audio from same point i.e user has closed the app after listening audio track1 till 1:45/25:50 and closed the app. so whenever this user open the app it should start the audio from 1:45/25:50 onward.

Comment: in Activity's `onDestroy` get player's current playing time, and save it somewhere. When user starts the app (in `onCreate` for example) get the saved value and seek player to that position.

Comment: cache your mediaplayer position in sharedPreferences

Answer (score 0):

Create custom wrapper classes for audio streams / files, after that you can store information in the wrapper and store it in the database;